# Regex to match space and a string until a forward slash

Tags: python, regex, django

I have two django urls,

```
(r'^groups/(?P<group>[\w|\W\-\.]{1,60})$')
(r'^groups/(?P<group>[\w|\W\-\.]{1,60})/users$'
```

The regex `([\w|\W\-\.])$` in the urls matches `soccer players` and `soccer players/users`. Can someone help get a regex that matches anything between `groups` and `/`. I want the regex to match anything after the groups until it encounters a /

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to do the following, which will match anything up to a slash:-

```
regexp = re.compile(r'^group/(?P<group>[^/]+)$')
```

For the case where you need to match urls like your example with a trailing `/user`, you simply add this to the expression:-

```
regexp = re.compile(r'^group/(?P<group>[^/]+)/users$')
```

If you needed to get a user id, for example, you could also use the same matching:-

```
regexp = re.compile(r'^group/(?P<group>[^/]+)/users/(?P<user>[^/]+)$')
```

Then you can get the result:-

```
match = regexp.match(url) # "group/soccer players/users/123"
if match:
    group = match.group("group") # "soccer players"
    user = match.group("user") # "123"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not seem to be matching the /. This is how I tried: >>> regex=re.compile(r'([^/]+)$')>>> print regex.match('soccer players')<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x108522738>>>> print regex.match('soccer players/users')
None

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you want. Do you want everything after the `group/` regardless? I thought you said you wanted anything between the `group` and the `/`?

Comment: I want it to match anything after group and until it encounters a /

Comment: Oh I think I've got what you are saying... I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did update my url with your expression.(r'^groups/(?P<group>([^/]+)(/.*)/users$'. When I try to capture the 'group' identifier i still get it as 'soccer players/user', instead of 'soccer players'. This is my request to the url. not sure, what is the mistake I am doing. curl -v http://some.thing.com:8000/groups/soccer%20players/users

Comment: Hope that works for you, accept the answer if you're happy with it... Yeah that won't work... Any reason why you aren't using it as is?

Comment: because I cannot change the url to not have the users in it. I can only change the regex part of it.

Comment: Ok, I've rewritten the answer from scratch, I think it will help you more than my previous examples